# Trigger Class Function with 'newTrigger'

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm somewhat new to google scripts and very new to using them with Forms. I'm creating a script that dynamically creates individual forms for users. To do this, I'm wrapping `FormApp.Create()` in a new Form class. I now want to have a method of the class called when the user clicks submit on their custom form but I can't figure out how to get the `ScriptApp.newTrigger` method to bind a class method to the trigger:

```
class Form {
  constructor(user) {
    var formName = user.name + '\'s Daily Journal'; 
    this.form = FormApp.create(formName); 
    this.user = user;

    /** This is where the problem is, I want this to bind this.submitFormAddOn but throws 'Script function not found: submitFormAddOn'. With and without the 'this.' prefix **/
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('submitFormAddOn')
    .forForm(this.form)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();

  }

  submitFormAddOn() {
    console.alert("Hello");
  }
}
```

Anyone have experience setting this up? Am I just not understanding this pattern?

Thank you!

Comment: Please elaborate on `but can't get it to work` - what is happening? Errors? Where is the trigger being created, if at all?  You can not declare classes in this way in Google Apps Script. You need to take the function constructor approach `var Form = function(user) { this.user = user; //etc }.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, to clarify, I'm getting an error `Script function not found: submitFormAddOn`. Even with the function constructor approach, I hit the same problem of how to reference `this. submitFormAddOn`. I think I'm not understanding the pattern of binding the trigger with the string name of an existing function, as documented here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newTrigger(String).

Comment: I think this is not possible. Think about it: If the program isn't running until the trigger activates, what instance of the `Form` class will the trigger act on?